# Why does websites give me Satoshies?

Tags: faucets

I am new to the bitcoin world and I am wondering why does some websites give me satoshies just by subscribing to it? (websites like moonbit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_faucet)

It looks like they are mostly advertising sites that want to introduce people to coins by giving them small amounts that they can then play with and get comfortable using them before buying larger amounts.